# Dynamic loading of textarea using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, database

How can I load an article (textarea) dynamically writing in the input text field (article ID) ? I want to check the ID in my DB and load the articles associated to it. Can you people give me an example ?

Comment: all should be done without any button: no form/buttons

Comment: Try searching the interwebs for jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax if possible.

```
<textarea id="id_name"></textarea>

<script>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "content_page.jsp", // .php or whatever file you are using
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data){
            jQuery("textarea#id_name").val(data);
        }
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Comment: @k.k what if the data displayed in the text area derives from a input text field ?

Comment: you need populate data into same page or from other page?

Answer (score 0):

An improved Version

```
<textarea id="id_name"></textarea>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "content_page.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data){
                 $("textarea#id_name").val(data);
         }
    }); 
});

</script>
```

More reading about this http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Really? I always thought that calling the jQuery object with a function was just an alias for `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @CallumMacrae My apologize !! I thought if the order is mixed we are in trouble!!